A question regarding the Reactive programming in general (not bound to a programming language)
I would like to verify whether my understand of Reactive Programming is correct in general, it is not tied to any specific programming language, but I use Java (using Reactor project) to illustrate the mind.
I understand the Reactive Programming is a new programming paradigm that is non-blocking. There are several benefits of it, let me quote one of the statement on internet below (which will be easier for explaining my question after):

asynchronous and non-blocking nature which allows applications to
handle a large number of concurrent operations efficiently. It is
ideal for building scalable systems that can accommodate increasing
loads without compromising performance

I feel the above statement is quite ambiguous when it says "handle a large number of concurrent operation", I mean what exactly does the word "handle" imply?
Let me first use the following Java reactive code as an example:
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

...
// a stream of integer numbers as data
Flux<Integer> intNumberFlux = Flux.range(1, 10).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

// we subscribe a consumer(observer) for the data stream
intNumberFlux.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + e));


System.out.println("Press a key to exit.");
System.in.read();

To be simple, I use one of the subscribe()'s signatures:
public final Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer)

So, the consumer is a lambda function which processes each of the data in the stream. The code looks simply & easy to understand.
When I run above code, the output shows me different threads are spawn  in consumber lambda for data processing:

But thinking about the scenario of REST API service when using Reactive Programming, my question is:
Do I understand correctly that with Reactive Programming, the REST API service can accept requests concurrently, because the main thread doesn't wait and blocking.  But when it comes to the real processing of each request (which is the consumer lambda), each request is processed by consumer lambda in a different thread & we are relying on a thread pool anyway? So, if data or requests come faster than we can process, it means our REST API service accepts them but we would end up with no thread available to process the them. So, we need some rate control to avoid out of memory incidence.  Am I right here?

In general, it's not correct. [Unless you do something specific,] it gets processed as data comes, i.e. in the original thread where it receives the requests.

But each consumer is run in a different thread, my code shows me that. Which part of my understanding is incorrect??  Isn't the original (main) thread non-blocking, but the spawn thread for each consumer come from a thread pool?  At least my code shows different thread id for each consumer at runtime.

You talk about REST API, which is ran on some HTTP server. Usually that one does use a thread pool. The mentioned subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer) is indeed done in the thread where that subscribe() is called. Your use-case with manual Flux creation and handling is not realistic. Look into a WebFlux for real reactive HTTP server: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux.html

@ArtemBilan two points I would like to clarify:


Spring WebFlux uses Reactor as its core dependency to implement the reactive programming model.


My question is around reactive web server.


So, I wonder which part of my understanding is incorrect? I hope the answer could be more clear. As you said the server does use thread pool & to my knowledge WebFlux is built on top of Reactor Project, then, under the hood, it should anyway uses the subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer) or similar fashion.

It's not spawn by a consumer, but by the publisher. Ex., [unless you do something specific,]  if you have 10 threads accepting the http requests, it would call the consumer in the same thread right after accepting the http request.

I.e, assume that the "consumer" is a "callback" function.

@IgorArtamonov, I haven't said the threads are spawn by the consumer, but I've been saying each request/data is processed by the "consumer" in a different thread (It's unclear to me who spawn it, who is the "publisher" in that context). So, if I say it in another way, do you agree that the original thread accepts requests one after another (non-blocking) but when it comes to processing the requests, a "publisher" spawn a thread and run the "consumer" logic in the spawn thread for each request?  May I also ask who is the "publisher" in the context of REST API service?  Thank you.

The Publisher is something that accepts the HTTP requests, and it has multiple threads to process incoming data. IO is not Reactive and it needs threads, so that's where this thread spawning happens, and you see those threads down in Consumer

Btw, there is always some "original thread" that accepts the requests "blocking". That's exactly why it is called "blocking", b/c it's something that blocks the CPU to wait for IO. And then you may have some abstraction layers that make it non-blocking, like Netty, and then Reactor.

My point is that you don't rely on the request management from the infrastructure, but create Flux and subscribe to it manually in your code. Therefore handling there happens exactly in the the thread you call that subscribe() and with that subscribe(Consumer) you are already out of reactive stream scope. Such a consumer in the end must be as lightweight (and non-blocking) as possible. That's why there are all those map/flatMap operator for events processing.

Answering to you question at the bottom: no, it's not correct, in general. But there could be configurations that work like you described.

No your understanding is faulty because you think that the request that is shown when you log is the actual thread the processed the request. Which it is not its actually the event loop that does the processing.
The thread you see there is the thread that scheduled the work on the event loop.
Reactors architecture is influenced by something called the LMAX Architecture which means there is an event loop, which has 2 circular buffers. And a scheduler that contains a small thread pool.
The schedulers take jobs and place them in the first circular buffer, the event loop takes jobs from the buffer and process them and places the result on the second ring buffer.
When the job is finished any thread from the scheduler will pick up the process result. Hence we are thread agnostic, and instead of having blocking work, we schedule and let a single thread work very very hard.
I suggest you read about the architecture here LMAX Architecture to get a better understanding.

You said "The schedulers take jobs and place them in the first circular buffer, the event loop takes jobs from the buffer and process them and places the result on the second ring buffer.",  do you mean the event loop takes jobs from the 1st buffer?  Do threads from scheduler takes job from the 2nd buffer to process?  In your illustration, the job is finished in which buffer? The 1st one or the 2nd one?

Did you read the link?
